# Изменить курсор маркера (drawingCursor) при перетаскивании

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Нужна помощь. Необходимо изменить курсор маркера при перетаскивании.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вы хотите сделать. Нужно поменять курсор мыши на метке при перетаскивании метки?

Comment: При перетаскивании маркера к маркеру применяется cursor: grabbing,мне нужен выставить cursor:move,  хотя при создании маркера в опции указано: `marker.options.set({
                cursor: 'move',
            })`

Comment: [пример][1]
  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/Novakand/1gx7tka0

Comment: кажется такой функциональности нет, напишите в техподдержку Яндекса, может они пойдут навстречу и добавят её.

Comment: Решение найдено: http://jsfiddle.net/Novakand/ebj6rwg5/

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так:

```
point.events.add('dragstart', (e) => {
  e.get('target').getOverlay().then((e) => {
    e.options.set('cursor', 'move')
  })
})
```